# Sending email in a goroutine

Tags: go

I am trying to programming an authentication system with golang.

After user successfully sign up, it will send an email confirmation to the user.

I am thinking to execute the send mail function in a goroutine. The code of send mail function looks like

```
func Send(email, link string) error {

    // Connect to the remote SMTP server.
    c, err := smtp.Dial("127.0.0.1:2525")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Set the sender and recipient.
    c.Mail("sender@example.org")
    c.Rcpt(email)
    // Send the email body.
    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer wc.Close()
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("Please confirm this email " + link)
    if _, err = buf.WriteTo(wc); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

If here an error is going to occur in the goroutine and response is already done(the user receive the response), how can I then handle the error?

Comment: Well that is up to you. You certainly should log the error. In terms of user experience - perhaps provide a "Request confirmation email resend" page where they can enter their email address and if their account is still "pending" the system can attempt to resend the email. I dare say the question as stated though is off-topic here.

Comment: How do you want to handle it?  You could send a push notification to the client, you could write something to the database, you could have a separate long-running background process waiting to handle errors in email goroutines, where the errors are communicated over a channel.  The only direct way to expose the error to another Go process is over a channel.  `Send` would take in an extra parameter (a channel) and rather than returning an error, it would send the error over the channel.

Comment: how can I send a push notification to the client, do you have some sample?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming:

1. A person signs up for an account
2. You send them a confirmation e-mail with an activation link
3. Once they click the link their account can now "do stuff"

If this is the case:

You should probably record the failure or success of this send mail operation to some kind of stateful store (SQL DB, mongo, leveldb, etc), then when a user logs in (or navigates to a page) you can notify them their account still needs to be confirmed (assuming either the send operation OR the URL clicking the confirmation link never happened) and offer to resend the e-mail.

Another option would be to make response to submitting the e-mail address wait for the e-mail to be sent (don't start a goroutine), but that might not scale well if you have many signups.. AND you would still need to maintain the state of who as clicked the activation link anyway. So the first option is better.